# given a number p, print value of n at which sum of (1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n) is greater than p

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

> Given a number 'p', develop a logic and write a Python program to determine the smallest integer 'n' in the sum of the reciprocals ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ⋅⋅⋅ + 1/n) that makes the summation to be greater than 'p'. Print the value of 'n' and the sum 's'.

> For example, when p=3, the sum of the reciprocals continues to be added until the value of s become greater than 3 i.e. n is 11

```
p=int(input())
new=0
for i in range(1,1000000):
    term=1/i
    sum1=new+term
    new=sum1
    if sum1>p:
        print(i,sum1)
        break
```

I have a doubt in how to set the upper limit of range. How do I decide what to put in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop `while True` with a stop condition:

```py
import itertools

p = 3
n, total = 0, 0
while True:
    n += 1
    total += 1 / n
    if total > p:
        break

print(n) # 11
```

---

Another approach is to use `itertools.count` to generate an infinite `for` loop, and stop it when a condition is met (either by `break` or `return`):

```py
import itertools

def first_greater(p):
    total = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(itertools.count(1), start=1):
        total += 1 / x
        if total > p:
            return i

print(first_greater(3)) # 11
```

---

A more condensed version (or "functional programming" approach): you can use `itertools.count` with `itertools.dropwhile` (or `itertools.takewhile`)

```py
import itertools

p = 3
series = itertools.accumulate(1 / x for x in itertools.count(1))
greaters = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[1] <= p, enumerate(series, start=1))
print(next(greaters)[0]) # 11
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have a doubt in how to set the upper limit of range. How do I decide what to put in this?

It's good that you've recognized this as a potential problem in your code! And the answer is: you *don't* know how many times you might need to run this loop. So it's not possible to decide what that upper bound is.

`for` loops are useful when you know how many times you want to loop. Is there another kind of loop you can use when you're not sure how many times you should be looping?

Comment: [perfectly fine `for` loop solution](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoAwEAPvfUWOLQoqXkTQV3gXRcWCrsu2Hnx9XQ0EhgyEn7hfVDcsKTE6eIrWE9/ROmdIh6AtzXYJRpXwcRV7TOe8TK26HpxjkHt1rYGGkHWofgw/ogAZlu@WcgSXUv0C) :-P

Comment: Lol that's fun. I learned something new about `iter` today!

Comment: Though I agree that's not "useful", just "possible" :-). [Maybe a more reasonable one](https://tio.run/##RY3BCgIxDETv/YocGyjCshcR9FdKXbtY3CYhpoJfX7vswXcbmHkjX3syzWfR3lflCsWyGvP2hlKF1WDhRhYgLUurbUuWnRO4QiHzhaSZR3QrK1CAsSHI1GrW0fP/ia9J/ASnGE1bfpRPjOEQ@wkRA0x4cTAo65DcQI60c9ecXk50/9svsPf5Bw).

Comment: Yet another new thing, cool! I would've used `from operator import truediv`. Since `1.__truediv__` is a syntax error, I was always under the impression that you couldn't get attributes out of ints. But apparently all you need is a space

Comment: How would you complete that, though? `itertools.repeat` the `1` or `functools.partial` it?. The one alternative I tried was `accumulate(1 / n for n in count(1))`, but I didn't like using `n` both inside and then again outside (I'm already not happy about writing `1` twice). Oh well, in the end that's all just for fun anyway, in this case they really shouldn't use `for`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking `partial(truediv, 1)`. `(1).__truediv__` is nicer in some ways though. Well ... "nicer" :)